# SQL Case statement specifiying condition in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have the the following query:

```
    SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tblOrders o
WHERE o.OrderId IN (SELECT [Value] FROM [dbo].[udf_GenerateVarcharTableFromStringList](@OrderId, ','))
AND
@ActiveInactive =
CASE 
WHEN 'Active' THEN (o.[orderactivedate] > o.[orderinactivedate])
WHEN 'Inactive' THEN (o.[orderactivedate] < o.[orderinactivedate]) 
END
```

This returns

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.
```

How would I get this to work? saying if the parameter is 'Active' then return records with the following criteria?

Comment: as an aside... You need to close the parens on that 'Active' Then statement.

Comment: added the closing parens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it an alternate way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tblOrders o
WHERE o.OrderId IN (SELECT [Value] FROM [dbo].[udf_GenerateVarcharTableFromStringList](@OrderId, ','))
AND ((@ActiveInactive = 'Active' AND o.[orderactivedate] > o.[orderinactivedate])
OR   (@ActiveInactive = 'Inactive' AND o.[orderactivedate] < o.[orderinactivedate]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tblOrders o
WHERE o.OrderId IN (SELECT [Value] FROM [dbo].[udf_GenerateVarcharTableFromStringList](@OrderId, ','))
AND
@ActiveInactive =
CASE 
WHEN (o.[orderactivedate] > o.[orderinactivedate]) then 'Active'
WHEN (o.[orderactivedate] < o.[orderinactivedate]) THEN 'Inactive'
END
```

Comment: Please use the curly brackets button to format code {}. Otherwise, good thinking

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add an OR condition? like

```
SELECT... WHERE ...
AND ((@ActiveInactive = 'Active' AND o.[orderactivedate] > o.[orderinactivedate])  OR
    (@ActiveInactive = 'Inactive' AND o.[orderactivedate] < o.[orderinactivedate]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an comparison expression in a CASE like that

I'd consider this option which change the comparison to a normal expression

```
...
AND
CASE @ActiveInactive 
WHEN 'Active' THEN DATEDIFF(day, o.[orderinactivedate], o.[orderactivedate])
WHEN 'Inactive' THEN DATEDIFF(day, o.[orderactivedate], o.[orderinactivedate])
END > 0
```

Or this, and you can have a computed column on the `SIGN()` expression

```
SIGN(DATEDIFF(day, o.[orderinactivedate], o.[orderactivedate])) =
              CASE WHEN @ActiveInactive WHEN 'Active' THEN 1 WHEN 'InActive' THEN -1 END
```