# Conditional CASE/IF in constructing T-SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a query in front-end code I'm trying to convert into a stored procedure.  The front-end code has conditional logic in it to construct the correct SQL based on form values.  I did not write the original SQL but have been tasked to do this conversion.

The issue I'm facing is I don't have enough knowledge/experience to go about doing this.  I have consulted these links as well for help, but they don't quite get me there:

[SQL: conditional statement in GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098398/sql-conditional-statement-in-group-by-clause)

[SQL Case statement specifiying condition in where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939225/sql-case-statement-specifiying-condition-in-where-clause?rq=1)

Pseudo-code:

```
WHERE b.ACTIVE=1
  AND YEAR(METRIC_YEAR) = @frmYear

IF @selOrg IS NOT NULL AND @selOrg != 'ALL'
     IF @selOrg = 'org1'
       AND ORG IN('org1','org2','org3') AND MEASURE_ID NOT IN(0,1,2,3,4)
     ELSE
       AND ORG = @selOrg
ELSE
     AND MEASURE_ID NOT IN(0,1,2,3,4)
```

Trying something as simple as this results in an "Incorrect syntax near END" error.

```
WHERE b.ACTIVE=1
  AND YEAR(METRIC_YEAR) = @frmYear
    AND
    CASE @selOrg 
    WHEN 'org1' THEN ORG IN('org1','org2','org3') AND MEASURE_ID NOT IN(0,1,2,3,4)
    END
```

Is what I want to do possible?  If so, what am I failing to see?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
WHERE b.ACTIVE=1
AND  YEAR(METRIC_YEAR) = @frmYear
AND (
        (@selOrg = 'org1' AND ORG IN('org1','org2','org3') AND MEASURE_ID NOT IN(0,1,2,3,4))
    OR  (@selOrg = 'ALL')
    )
```

Depending on what your criteria is going to be though it may be beneficial to do separate queries -

```
IF @selOrg = 'org1'
    BEGIN 
        SELECT  ...
        FROM    Table
        WHERE b.ACTIVE=1
        AND  YEAR(METRIC_YEAR) = @frmYear   
        AND ORG IN('org1','org2','org3') 
        AND MEASURE_ID NOT IN(0,1,2,3,4);
    END
ELSE IF @selOrg = 'All'
    BEGIN 
        SELECT  ...
        FROM    Table
        WHERE b.ACTIVE=1
        AND  YEAR(METRIC_YEAR) = @frmYear;
    END
```

This may seem like extra work, but you may get improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

Examples for "Case"

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END,
   Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber;
```

or

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Name, "Price Range" = 
      CASE 
         WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
         WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
         WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
         WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
         ELSE 'Over $1000'
      END
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber ;
```